# ERROR: This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 3.6 or newer

Tags: android-studio

I had Android Studios version 3.5 and it asked me to upgrade to 3.6, so I upgraded. But 3.6 didn't work really well with me, so I switched back to 3.5

Unfortunately I created a new project in version 3.6 and after changing back to 3.5, I couldn't run the project anymore.

It gave me this error:

```
ERROR: This version of Android Studio cannot open this project, please retry with Android Studio 3.6 or newer.
```

What should I do?

Comment: have you try removing the `.idea` directory? Make a backup first.

Comment: I tried removing it, didn't work @ישואוהבאותך

Answer (score 1):

try to change the build.gradle file from exsiting one to " 3.5.3 "
and also try to change the gradle-wapper.properties file from 
from--> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip 
to--> " distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip "

Comment: Please proofread your answer.  `gradle-wapper.properties` is not the correct name.  More details about what you mean by `change the build.gradle file from exsiting one to " 3.5.3 "` would also help.